# How to create []string from struct in Go

Tags: struct, go

How can I create `[]string` from struct's values in Go? For example, in the following struct:

```
type Person struct {
    Height    float64
    Weight    float64
    Name    string
    Born    string
}

Tim := Person{174.5, 68.3, "Tim", "United States"}
```

What I want to get is the following one:

```
[]string{"174.5", "68.3", "Tim", "United States"}
```

Since I want to save each record which is derived from the struct to a CSV file, and `Write` method of the `*csv.Writer` requires to take the data as `[]string`, I have to convert such struct to `[]string`.

Of course I can define a method on the struct and have it return `[]string`, but I'd like to know a way to avoid calling every field (i.e. person.Height, person.Weight, person.Name...) since the actual data includes much more field.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There may be a simpler and/or more idiomatic way to do it, but what comes to mind for me is to use the `reflect` package like this:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

func main() {
    type Person struct {
        Height float64
        Weight float64
        Name   string
        Born   string
    }

    Tim := Person{174.5, 68.3, "Tim", "United States"}

    v := reflect.ValueOf(Tim)

    var ss []string
    for i := 0; i < v.NumField(); i++ {
        ss = append(ss, fmt.Sprintf("%v", v.Field(i).Interface()))
    }

    fmt.Println(ss)
}
```

Comment: I was just reading the documentation of the package and trying to define a method, but couldn't succeed. Thanks a lot. The only reason you passed a pointer instead of a value to the `reflect.ValueOf` method is `reflect.Elem()` requires only interface or pointer, right?

Comment: @user2360798 Good question.  I had overcomplicated that line; I've fixed it now: `reflect.ValueOf(Tim)` is sufficient.